# Can I use Google Analytics API to customize my layout?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been looking at this for a moment now but couldn't really find anything similar on Google.

As the title says, I would like to customize some layout in my website based on (let's say) the gender of the visitor. If it's a male, show something, and if it's a female, show another thing.

Is this possible with the Google Analytics API?

What I had in mind was something like this:

```
if google.analytics.current_user.gender = 'male'
  <p>You are a boy!</p>
else
  <p>You are a girl!</p>
```

(I don't expect any code answer I just want to know if it's feasible so I can look more into it myself).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

It is possible by using an A/B testing tool that offers up different versions of a page based on conditions, and Google offer Optimize for free to do this https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9204024

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately, I see that you can only run Optimize for 90 days if I understood correctly so I'll find something else.